# Using Linq in VS2005 causes error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual studio 2005. Why is this line not supported?

```
using System.Linq;
```

Error:

> Error  1   Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute values must be enclosed in quotation marks.
>
> Error  2   The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq on visual studio 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825613/linq-on-visual-studio-2005)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is not supported until .NET Framework v3.5, and visual studio 2005 supports .net v2.0 at max.

There are some [workaround](https://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/) to use LINQ with .NET 2.0 but you will still need Visual Studio 2008 minimum!

Comment: thank u for reply ..how i can achieve Autocomplete textbox result

Comment: @user3552061 - Please follow this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13892238/922198